# How to run specific code after all tests are executed?

Tags: pytest

I would like to run specific code after all the tests are executed using pytest

for eg: I open up a database connection before any tests are executed. And I would like to close the connection after all the tests are executed.

How can i achieve this with py.test? Is there a fixture or some thing that can do this?

Answer (score 51):

You can use a autouse [fixture](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) with session scope:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def db_conn():
    # Will be executed before the first test
    conn = db.connect()
    yield conn
    # Will be executed after the last test
    conn.disconnect()
```

You can then also use `db_conn` as an argument to a test function:

```
def test_foo(db_conn):
    results = db_conn.execute(...)
```

Comment: `yield_fixture` is deprecated: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/yieldfixture.html. In current version of pytest you can already use `yield` inside a regular fixture declared with `@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)`.

Comment: @ccpizza Indeed, thanks! I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: When you use `autouse` here, doesn't it mean that you don't need to add it to the test call? From https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html :
```In this example, the append_first fixture is an autouse fixture. Because it happens automatically, both tests are affected by it, even though neither test requested it. That doesn’t mean they can’t be requested though; just that it isn’t necessary.```

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś Correct, but that's exactly what my post says? "That doesn’t mean they can’t be requested though; just that it isn’t necessary." and "You can then also use `db_conn` as an argument to a test function" are the exact same thing, no?

Comment: This is probably the most circumspect way to implement a `def afterAll(self)` function. It can't be this implicit.

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your conftest.py

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """
    Called after whole test run finished, right before
    returning the exit status to the system.
    """
    ... # Your code goes here
```

converse of `def pytest_sessionstart(session)`

Comment: This was the only example that worked for me. I needed to delete a Sqlite db file *after* the test run and this did the trick without tests failing due to 'peewee.OperationalError: no such table: [table_name]' because the db instance was evidently getting deleted while tests were still running.